# Check all checkboxes in a table which row is not hidden

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with checkbox in every row and filtering mechanism.

```js
        function toggle(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('cbox');
            for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
            }
        }
        
        function FilterTable() {
                
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
            input = document.getElementById("txtFilter");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("tblEmployees");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
                if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtFilter" onkeyup="FilterTable()"  />
 <table id="tblEmployees">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"></th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>John 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>John 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>John 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>Mark 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>Mark 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Currently, when I check the main checkboxes in the header, all checkbox in the table gets checked, even if the row is hidden when I filter the table.
What I need to do is to check only the checkboxes that are not hidden.

For example, I filter "John". 3 rows will remain visible and the 2 "Mark" records will be hidden. Then, I tick the checkbox in the header, only the 3 "John" records should be checked. So when I clear the filter, the 2 "Mark" records remain unchecked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Version 1: Minimal change on your code

You simply need to check for the `style.display` of the parenting row in your function `toggle`.

```
function toggle(source){
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('cbox');
    for(var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++){
        //REM: Fetch the closest <tr> element
        const tTR = checkboxes[i].closest('tr');
        
        //REM: Only change if not display "none"
        if(tTR.style.display !== 'none'){
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked
        }
    }
}
```

### Version 2: Adding forEach

Instead of `style.display` you could also make use of the [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden) property and instead of a `for-loop` you could go for [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
function toggle(source){
    document.getElementsByName('cbox').forEach(checkbox => {
        //REM: Only change if not display "none"
        if(checkbox.closest('tr').style.display !== 'none'){
            checkbox.checked = source.checked
        }
    })
}
```

### Version 3: Use classes instead of styles

This is the way I would approach it, using classes instead of setting `style`.

```js
function toggle(source){
  document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.Hidden) [name=cbox]').forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.checked = source.checked
  })
};
        
function FilterTable(){             
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("txtFilter");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("tblEmployees");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++){
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
      if (td){
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              tr[i].classList.remove('Hidden')
          } else {
              tr[i].classList.add('Hidden')
          }
      }
  }
};
```

```css
.Hidden{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtFilter" onkeyup="FilterTable()"  />
 <table id="tblEmployees">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"></th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>John 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>John 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>John 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>Mark 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>Mark 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: They all work. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You want to check if the table-row is hidden before you check the box.

So, within your `for` loop I've added an `if` statement which searches for the `closest('tr')`, and checks if it's hidden or not.

```js
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('cbox');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    if(checkboxes[i].closest('tr').style.display != "none") {
      checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
  }
}

function FilterTable() {

  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("txtFilter");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("tblEmployees");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtFilter" onkeyup="FilterTable()" />
<table id="tblEmployees">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"></th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox" /></td>
      <td>John 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox" /></td>
      <td>John 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox" /></td>
      <td>John 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox" /></td>
      <td>Mark 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox" /></td>
      <td>Mark 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If the answer suits you, please mark it as the answer (V-mark on the left of my answer)

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to do this but a simple way to solve it would be to add a data attribute to your hidden rows and then check for that in your filter function.

I'd recommend doing this over checking for a style property to avoid coupling your script too closely to the particulars of how something is styled.

```js
function toggle(source) {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('cbox');
            var tr = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
            for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                if(tr[i].dataset.hidden === "true"){
                  continue;
                 }
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
            }
        }
        
        function FilterTable() {
                
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
            input = document.getElementById("txtFilter");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("tblEmployees");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
                if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].dataset.hidden = "false";
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].dataset.hidden = "true";
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtFilter" onkeyup="FilterTable()"  />
 <table id="tblEmployees">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"></th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>John 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>John 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>John 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>Mark 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox"/></td>
        <td>Mark 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

You could also do the same more directly with a ['hidden'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute, and avoid the redundancy of having both a 'style' and a data attribute.